# How to get innerHTML or innerText of button in angular 2/4 from within template?

Tags: angular

How can I access a button's 'innerHTML' or 'innerText' in the template in angular2/4? Do I have to create a function to get it out of the $event or is there something I can use in the template directly? I want to do something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'bolden-text': mylist.indexOf($currentDOMElement.srcElement.innerText) > -1}">Bananas</button>
```

Comment: If its inside your template, why not bind the button contents to a member string variable?

Comment: The buttons are hardcoded and I have about 10 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a template variable via `#variableName` and access its properties in template.

```
<button #btnTest type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'bolden-text': mylist.indexOf(btnTest.textContent) > -1}">Bananas</button>
{{ btnTest.textContent }} <!-- sample for button -->
```

Comment: Can #btnText be assigned dynamically?

Comment: @Rolando I didn't try this before. AFAIK it's impossible.

Comment: Just tried your solution and had issues. Looks close, if you change '$event.srcElement' to 'btnTest.srcElement', it works. Make the correction in your post and I will mark it as correct unless someone posts shortly after this.

Comment: @Rolando why do you need `srcElement`? see this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6f1buv?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: btnTest.textContent works fine, thanks. Your right, I don't need srcElement. Still, your answer needs changing from $event.srcElement.. to btnTest.textContent in the ngClass.